# Is there a way to produce a count of multiple categories over a resampled date indexed pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, indexed by date, containing information about the magnitude of floods - none, small, medium and large which are represented numerically by 0,1,2 and 3 respectively, see below (edited product of df.head(15).to_dict()):

```
     date    flood
2001-01-01   0.0
2001-01-02   0.0
2001-01-03   0.0
2001-01-04   1.0
2001-01-05   1.0
2001-01-06   1.0
2001-01-07   0.0
2001-01-08   0.0
2001-01-09   2.0
2001-01-10   0.0
2001-01-11   3.0
2001-01-12   0.0
2001-01-13   0.0
2001-01-14   2.0
2001-01-15   0.0
```

I would like to resample by month (or other specified time period) and produce a count of the frequency of each category occurring. So the output would be something like this, for example:

```
            0     1     2     3
    date
1-1-2001    23    6     1     1
1-2-2001    20    7     1     0
1-3-2001    30    1     0     0
...
```

Any ideas how this might be achieved?

Thanks!!

Comment: can you share result of `df.head(15).to_dict()`. So its easier for us to create sample dataframe of your data.

Comment: consider pivot table? 
 `df.pivot_table(index='date',columns='flood',aggfunc=len,fill_value=0)` ? assuming date is a column

Comment: I have changed the example data to the output of df.head(15).to_dict(). I will have a go with pivot, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following approach, basically you need to `groupby` the `date` as well as `flood`, and because there are only 2 columns (and you are grouping by 2 groups), you need an additional dummy column (which is why I simply `reset_index` below):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df_count = df.reset_index().groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M'),'flood']).count().unstack()

# Just to restore the columns, 
# which became a multi-index because of the dummy variable I created using reset_index
df_count.columns = df_count.columns.droplevel()
```

which gives you

```
flood       0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
date                          
2001-01-31    9    3    2    1
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, though it seems it is only giving me the date column now:

Comment: Oh, the dates are the indices in your dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

```
# convert date column to datetime format (assuming it isn't already)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)
# set all days to 1
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(day=1))

# count using pivot table:
result = pd.pivot_table(df, index='date', columns='flood', aggfunc=len)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
flood       0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
date                          
2001-01-01    9    3    2    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @anky_91 above, who gave me:

```
df.pivot_table(index='date',columns='flood',aggfunc=len,fill_value=0)
```

This did the trick, producing the following:

```
Size    0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0
date                
2001-01-01  1   0   0   0
2001-01-02  1   0   0   0
2001-01-03  1   0   0   0
2001-01-04  1   0   0   0
2001-01-05  1   0   0   0
...AND SO ON
```

I can then go and resample().sum() for each time period...

THANK YOU SO MUCH :D

Comment: `df.groupby(df['date'].dt.to_period('M')).flood.value_counts().unstack('flood')` would be an edge faster.